# dropdownlist with table from externe database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using asp.net mvc with entityframwork. I added in my models a new item Linq - to Sql classes and I have named: StickerPrinter.dbml. The database is an existing database

I added a table: Verploegen_TEST_Location.

But now I try to Add a dropdownlist. Because Verploegen_TEST_Location has five locations.

see image
[image]

I have this in mvc now:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Verploegen_TEST_Location location = new Verploegen_TEST_Location();


        }
```

if I do f12 on Verploegen_TEST_Location location I see all the properties of that table. But I am little bit struggling with the Index method. Because Normally I am using DBContext like this:

```
 public class StickerPrinterContext:DbContext
    {

        public StickerPrinterContext():base("StickerPrinterContext")
        {}

        public DbSet<Printer>printers  { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vestiging>Vestigingen { get; set; }
        public DbSet <Vendor>Vendors  { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Verploegen_TEST_Location> Locations { get; set; }
    }
```

But I think to add the table in the stickerPrinterContext is now not necessary.

So to build the INdex method with the dropdown function with LINQ?

Thank you

So if I go to Verploegen_TEST_Location I see this:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.[Verploegen TEST$Location]")]
    public partial class Verploegen_TEST_Location : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private System.Data.Linq.Binary _timestamp;

        private string _Code;

        private string _Name;

        private string _Name_2;

        private string _Address;
```

And I have my index controller now like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
          IList<Verploegen_TEST_Location> locationList = new List<Verploegen_TEST_Location>();
            var query = from location in db.Locations
                        select location;

            return View(locationList);


        }
```

But If I run the code now, I get this error:

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

```
StickerPrinterWeb.DAL.Verploegen_TEST_Location: : EntityType 'Verploegen_TEST_Location' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Locations: EntityType: EntitySet 'Locations' is based on type 'Verploegen_TEST_Location' that has no keys defined
```

So what I did was trying add in models a new class:

```
public class Verploegen_TEST_Location
    {
    }
```

but then I will get an error:

Code    Description Project Line    Column  Suppression State
CS0260  Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'Verploegen_TEST_Location'; another partial declaration of this type exists StickerPrinterWeb   8   18  Active

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
```

And I have read this:

```
To conclude, Linq to Sql dbml file is an auto-generated file that you should never really need to look the code. The Visual Designer is powerful enough to handle all modifications possible with Linq to Sql.
```

But how to handle the INdex method then?

You mean I have to do this?

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.[Verploegen TEST$Location]")]
    public partial class Verploegen_TEST_Location : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private System.Data.Linq.Binary _timestamp;

        [Key]
        private string _Code;

        private string _Name;

        private string _Name_2;

        private string _Address;
```

Because above in the file I see this:

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace StickerPrinterWeb.Models
```

[image]

and I have a viewModel like this:

```
public class Vm_LocationsList
    {
        [Key]
        public string _Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I have it now like this:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // declare your view model if you have any
            var vm_LocationList = new Vm_LocationsList();

            var locationList = new List<Verploegen_TEST_Location>();
            var query = (from location in db.Locations
                         select location).ToList();

            var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var items in query)
            {
                selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = items.Name, Value = items.Code });
            }

            model.SelectList = selectList;
            return View(model);
        }
```

but where is the decleration of model?

Ok, thank you. But so I dont have to edit the

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.[Verploegen TEST$Location]")]
    public partial class Verploegen_TEST_Location : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private System.Data.Linq.Binary _timestamp;

        [Key]
        private string _Code;
```

What I did first?

But I still get the error:

```
StickerPrinterWeb.DAL.Verploegen_TEST_Location: : EntityType 'Verploegen_TEST_Location' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

For cleareness. This is my Verploegen_TEST_Location: class part of it:

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace StickerPrinterWeb.Models
{
    using System.Data.Linq;
    using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009R2-TEST")]
    public partial class StickerPrinterDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
    {

        private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void InsertVerploegen_TEST_Location(Verploegen_TEST_Location instance);
    partial void UpdateVerploegen_TEST_Location(Verploegen_TEST_Location instance);
    partial void DeleteVerploegen_TEST_Location(Verploegen_TEST_Location instance);
    #endregion

        public StickerPrinterDataContext() : 
                base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VERPLOEGEN_NAV2009R2_TESTConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public StickerPrinterDataContext(string connection) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public StickerPrinterDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public StickerPrinterDataContext(string connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public StickerPrinterDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<Verploegen_TEST_Location> Verploegen_TEST_Locations
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<Verploegen_TEST_Location>();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.[Verploegen TEST$Location]")]
    public partial class Verploegen_TEST_Location : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private System.Data.Linq.Binary _timestamp;

        [Key]
        private string _Code;

        private string _Name;

        private string _Name_2;

        private string _Address;

        private string _Address_2;

        private string _City;

        private string _Phone_No_;

        private string _Phone_No__2;

        private string _Telex_No_;

        private string _Fax_No_;

        private string _Contact;

        private string _Post_Code;

        private string _County;

        private string _E_Mail;

        private string _Home_Page;

        private string _Country_Region_Code;

        private byte _Use_As_In_Transit;

        private byte _Require_Put_away;

        private byte _Require_Pick;

        private string _Cross_Dock_Due_Date_Calc_;

        private byte _Use_Cross_Docking;

        private byte _Require_Receive;

        private byte _Require_Shipment;

        private byte _Bin_Mandatory;

        private byte _Directed_Put_away_and_Pick;

        private int _Default_Bin_Selection;

        private string _Outbound_Whse__Handling_Time;

        private string _Inbound_Whse__Handling_Time;

        private string _Put_away_Template_Code;

        private byte _Use_Put_away_Worksheet;

        private byte _Pick_According_to_FEFO;

        private byte _Allow_Breakbulk;

        private int _Bin_Capacity_Policy;

        private string _Open_Shop_Floor_Bin_Code;

        private string _Inbound_Production_Bin_Code;

        private string _Outbound_Production_Bin_Code;

        private string _Adjustment_Bin_Code;

        private byte _Always_Create_Put_away_Line;

        private byte _Always_Create_Pick_Line;

        private int _Special_Equipment;

        private string _Receipt_Bin_Code;

        private string _Shipment_Bin_Code;

        private string _Cross_Dock_Bin_Code;

        private string _Outbound_BOM_Bin_Code;

        private string _Inbound_BOM_Bin_Code;

        private string _Base_Calendar_Code;

        private byte _Use_ADCS;

        private string _Counter_Nos_;

        private string _Payment_Method_comb_;

        private string _Account_No__Cash;

        private string _Account_No__Pay_Card;

        private string _Account_No__Cash_Deliver;

        private string _Account_No__Pay_Card_Deliver;

        private decimal _X_coord;

        private decimal _Y_coord;

        private byte _Autom__Create_Whse__Shipment;

        private byte _Block_for_Item_Availability;

        private string _Printer_Name;
```

Comment: do you have a connection string named "StickerPrinterContext" in your web.config? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Add primary key for Verploegen_TEST_Location table in database, update the edmx file and you will be good to go. You dont have to add your own `public class Verploegen_TEST_Location`

Comment: But it is an existing database and an existing table.Code is the primary key in the table:Verploegen_TEST_Location.

Comment: Is it now better to make a viewModel? But how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into your first error message:

`Locations: EntityType: EntitySet 'Locations' is based on type 'Verploegen_TEST_Location' that has no keys defined`

From my experience, make sure you added `KeyAttribute` inside all of your DBML model classes primary key fields/properties to use them in `DbSet` context (may require manual editing on your DBML designer file, or adding primary key on underlying DB then regenerating DBML structure).

Regarding second error message:

`CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'Verploegen_TEST_Location'; another partial declaration of this type exists`

Since the model classes are declared as partial, you can't simply adding other same model class without using partial modifier on it, but you can create separate viewmodels to communicate with view and perform CRUD into model classes.

If you have already set primary key fields/properties on all of DBML table classes, you can try passing drop down list content into view as `List<SelectListItem>` using either `Html.DropDownList` or `Html.DropDownListFor`.

**Edit**: I modified the given sample to fit for your code description, including Model & Controller routine here:

```
// Model
public class Vm_LocationsList
{
    [Key]
    public string _Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // add this line to include drop down list items to your view
    public List<SelectListItem> SelectList { get; set; }
}

// Controller
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // this is your view model declaration
    var vm_LocationList = new Vm_LocationsList();

    var locationList = new List<Verploegen_TEST_Location>();
    var query = (from location in db.Locations
                 select location).ToList();

    var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var items in query)
    {
        selectList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = items.Name, Value = items.Code });
    }

    vm_LocationList.SelectList = selectList;
    return View(vm_LocationList);
}

// View (strongly-typed version)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Code, Model.SelectList)
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Edited my answer to match your model declaration. Note that you need to include a property declared as `SelectListItem` into your viewmodel, then pass it into view.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But so I dont have to edit the [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.[Verploegen TEST$Location]")]
    public partial class Verploegen_TEST_Location : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private System.Data.Linq.Binary _timestamp;

        [Key]
        private string _Code;